# How to get correct site context in micro-site implementation in Sitecore 8.1

Tags: sitecore-client, multisite, site-configuration

I have implement micro-site solution in Sitecore 8.1 as described in below post
[Set up microsites in Sitecore 8.1](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/5115/set-up-microsites-in-sitecore-8.1)

but we are not getting correct site context for each individual micro-sites. Following code is being used to get site context:

```
var url = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url;
var siteContext = Sitecore.Sites.SiteContextFactory.GetSiteContext(url.Host, url.PathAndQuery);
string siteSettingsRoot = siteContext.Properties["SiteSettingsNode"].ToString();
```

and below is `sitedefinition` for micro-sites

```
name="micrositemainone" hostName="microsite.mysite.com" virtualFolder="/company1" startItem="/Home"
physicalFolder="/company1" rootPath="/sitecore/content/Site/Microsites/company1" SiteSettingsNode="/sitecore/content/Site/Microsites/company1/Site Settings"

name="micrositemain" hostName="microsite.mysite.com" virtualFolder="/"  startItem="/Home"
physicalFolder="/" rootPath="/sitecore/content/Site/Microsite/Main"  SiteSettingsNode="/sitecore/content/Site/Microsites/Main/Site Settings"
```

When I browse http://microsite.mysite.com/en/company1 it shows content specific to company1 but it returns `SiteSettingsNode` of **micrositemain** site not **micrositemainone**
In this case I should get `sitecontext` of `micrositemainone`. Looks like need to change in code where I access Sitecore context.

**Note: we have two settings**

1. `Languages.AlwaysStripLanguage = true`
2. `languageEmbedding=always` in `linkprovider` element

because we already have running live site, so I can't change these for ex:
www.mysite.com/en
www.mysiteca.com/en
www.mysiteca.com/fr-ca

**UPDATE: 05-08-2017**

If I have virtualFolder="/company1" & physicalFolder="/company1" in sitedefinition see below

[image]

As we can see `/en/` is already added in as prefix that's why might be If I update both `virtualFolder` & `physicalFolder` value to `"/en/company1"` I got 404 page

**UPDATE: 05-09-2017**

**Option 1:**

Ok so I changed `Languages.AlwaysStripLanguage` value to `false` with following settings for micro-sites:

```
virtualFolder="/en/company1"

physicalFolder="/en/company1"
```

and now I'm getting correct `sitecontext` for each microsites but getting problem with other 4 sites i.e. If I browse `http://mysite.com` & `http://mysiteca.com` I got following error message:

```
This page isn’t working
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
```

to load other sites properly I updated `virtualFolder="/en"` & `physicalFolder="/en"` in all 4 sites's `sitedefinition.config` file.

**Option 2**

I kept virtualFolder="/company1" & physicalFolder="/company1" as it is for micro-sites but to get correct site context I made below change in function:

```
 public static Sitecore.Sites.SiteContext CurrentSiteNode
        {
            get
            {
                var url = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url;
                var siteContext= Sitecore.Sites.SiteContextFactory.GetSiteContext(url.Host, url.PathAndQuery);
                if (siteContext.StartPath != null && siteContext.StartPath.Contains("Microsites") && url.PathAndQuery.Split('/').Length > 2)
                {
                    var currentsite = "/" + url.PathAndQuery.Split('/')[2];
                    return Sitecore.Sites.SiteContextFactory.GetSiteContext(url.Host,currentsite); // currentsite = company1 & url.Host = microsite.mysite.com
                }

                return siteContext;
            }
        }
```

So in **option 1** I have to

1. update `Languages.AlwaysStripLanguage = false` (I'm not sure do I really have to make this change because it's value is trued from the beginning of the project)
2. update all 4 site's `sitedefinition.config` file

And in **option 2**, the change in only at one place.

Which option would you suggest?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason why you are receiving the `SiteContext` as **micrositemain** is because `url.Host` will return `microsite.mysite.com`.

Please see updated `SiteDefinition` below:

```
name="micrositemainone"
hostName="microsite.mysite.com" 
virtualFolder="/{language_here}/company1" //ex: /en/company1
startItem="/en/Home"
physicalFolder="/{language_here}/company1" 
rootPath="/sitecore/content/Site/Microsites/company1" 
SiteSettingsNode="/sitecore/content/Site/Microsites/company1/Site Settings"

name="micrositemain" 
hostName="microsite.mysite.com" 
virtualFolder="/"  
startItem="/Home"
physicalFolder="/" 
rootPath="/sitecore/content/Site/Microsite/Main"  
SiteSettingsNode="/sitecore/content/Site/Microsites/Main/Site Settings"
```

**UPDATE**

I have tested the above locally and saw that you need to update the setting `Languages.AlwaysStripLanguage` to `false` and add the above changes to the `SiteDefinition.config`.

Based on your question updates, I would suggest to manage it through the code, which is, option 2. The reason because you will have more control of it.

Comment: I tried adding `/en/` in virtualFolder/physicalFolder but after that change when I browsed http://microsite.mysite.com/en/company1 site it give me 404 error....

Comment: For micro-site we are using only English language so I'm using only /en

I got below 404 URL after I browsed that ( http://microsite.mysite.com/en/company1 )
`404 URL`  --> http://microsite.mysite.com/en/page-not-found?item=%2fcompany1&user=extranet%5canonymous&site=micrositemain

As per this post( https://hishaamn.wordpress.com/2016/12/22/sitecore-multi-sites-with-same-domain-but-different-sitecore-item-node/ ) I was supposed to make two edits( Linkprovider & StripLanguage settings ) but I didn't make and I explained the reason in post at the bottom.

Comment: fyi These sitedifinition doesn't have language attribute because none of other have this attribute...

as you can see in 404 URL it's does have &site=micrositemain Do we need to do anything in micrositemain sitedefinition

Comment: In the virtualFolder and physicalFolder just add the language. Example: /fr-ca/company1

Comment: but why should I add this because I don't any any content for fr-ca in language It contains only en content...If I'm not mistaken

Comment: if we check 404 URL ( microsite.mysite.com/en/page-not-found?item=%2fcompany1&user=extranet%5canonymous&site=micrositemain ) looks like sitecore searching items( company1 ) in content editor which is actually a rootpath not starting point ( Home ) and also it should search in micrositemainone not in micrositemain sitedefinition

Comment: please see my update in POST

Comment: I have tested this on my local instance and it is working. The only difference I see is the `Languages.AlwaysStripLanguage`. Can you set the value to `false` and also let the language in the `virtualFolder` and `physicalFolder`

Comment: You're awesome....please see my updated post with 2 options.....

Comment: Please see updated answer

Comment: Great...As of now Option 2 is working for micro-sites...but just wanted to check if this solution would work for long run...
and as usual you are the showstopper for every sitecore issues....
:)

Comment: Thanks. Maybe you will need to check on this again in the future. If the answer has helped you can you please marked it

Comment: yeah sure If I see any issue with this option in future I will check again but as of now we are good to go